# Composite Primary key vs. Auto-Increment Primary key

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a little advice on how to proceed with a table that we have been importing case data into from another department:

```
  Id    CreationDate                ClosedDate  LastUpdateDate            Name                                 Description          
DE5838  2015-06-02 06:14:11.11      NULL        2015-06-02 06:19:33.33    Look UP : Should be updated ...      Description : This is not a defect…          
DE5834  2015-06-01 16:16:03.03      NULL        2015-06-01 16:24:19.19    Sync error for Ultimate packages...  We are getting an error ....         
DE5822  2015-06-01 10:37:10.10      NULL        2015-06-01 10:37:10.10    Terminal subscription has expired... For given terminal serial number…            
DE5818  2015-06-01 09:53:44.44      NULL        2015-06-01 09:53:44.44    No Option Code…                      Allie pulled the report....
```

For quite some time, (and without much of a data definition from the outside department), we have been treating the ID field as the PK - Only now we are starting to see that the other department has been recycling these ID numbers (*I know, I know - **REALLY** bad idea*).
SO, what that leaves us with is data that they we are trying to import - but our table will not accept it as the unique identifier is already assigned to case data.
What I was thinking might be a good solution would be to change the PK to a composite with ID and CreationDate (which we believe *may be* the way that the outside department is creating the data), or I could add an auto-incremented ID field and assign this as a unique identifier to all of the data that we already have. 
But as this is an inherited mess that I recently walked into, I am looking for any advice in how to proceed with this.

Comment: I would use an identity field, personally, if I don't know for a fact that the PK consists of the columns I think it does.

Comment: @TabAlleman, And they have been using a different unique Identifier all along for their data, I am pretty sure that it does not make a difference which I use going forward. I guess I am wondering if either of the options for an ID risky to implement. I mean with an new ID field I am adding a column, but with the composite, I am altering the PK - thoughts on this?

Comment: There are certain queries that you may need to write one day that will be easier if you have a single identity column.   Other than that, I can't really think of much of a difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a composite key not only will make you alter the index, but all tables that reference the primary key will also have to have the additional column added.  I would recommend adding an identity field on the table.  Rename your current ID field to something like ReferenceNumber.  Then update all foreign references in other tables to use the new ID.  Then you could convert the foreign key fields to also be integer fields.  This would save space in your database ultimately and probably result in faster joins in the future.

Then you would also have to make sure any interfaces are updated to do lookups by ReferenceNumber / dateor the new ID.